# How to remove numbers from a list which contain repeated digits?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

I have a pretty long list of integer numbers in a given range, most of them contain numbers with repeated digits like in the example below.

`[123456, 889756, 854123, 997886, 634178]`

My goal is to remove the ones with repeated digits or get a new list with numbers having only distinct digits:

`[123456, 854123, 634178]`

Is there a nice way how to do this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A simple way (but maybe not "nice") is to convert the number to a string and this to a set of characters. If set and string have same "len" there are no repeated digits in it. You must apply this test to each list item in a loop or list comprehension.

Comment: The answer with that exact technique was posted 2 mins ago...

Comment: @VexenCrabtree The Android app of Stack Overflow has some update delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set` on the string representation of the number to see how many digits make it into the set. If that is the same number of digits as the original number has, it passes the test:

```
lst = [123456, 889756, 854123, 997886, 634178]
result = [n for n in lst if len(set(str(n))) == len(str(n))]

print(result)
```

As commented below, benchmarks confirm that it is advantageous to perform an inline assignment to a temporary variable:

```
result = [n for n in lst if len(set(s := str(n))) == len(s)]
```

Comment: Isn't Python awesome at this kind of thing :-)

Comment: The OP said "a large number" of integers... but the answer here does str(n) twice, and len(...) twice. By using a more traditional for loop, you could save str(n) and len(,,.) and re-use. Maybe present both options in your answer, and let the OP choose which he thinks appropriate and allow time testing if required.

Comment: Tested this code in my problem and it worked perfect! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Vexen, true, `str` is called twice, but I don't see how you can avoid calling `len` twice without reverting to more expensive logic. I think that the overhead for the double call of `str` is minor if the numbers are in a reasonable range, and adding a temporary variable to somehow avoid it, also comes at a cost. A traditional `for` loop will have to call `append`, which is slower than list comprehension. I don't think it will beat list comprehension despite the double `str` call.

Comment: Maybe `:=` operator would help here: `result = [n for n in lst if len(set(s := str(n))) == len(s)]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely, maybe... To be benchmarked.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for making the effort, @AndrejKesely!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, with `re`:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(\d).*\1")
lst = [123456, 889756, 854123, 997886, 634178]

lst = [i for i in lst if not r.search(str(i))]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[123456, 854123, 634178]
```

---

EDIT: Small benchmark:

```
from timeit import timeit


lst = [123456, 889756, 854123, 997886, 634178] * 10000


def re_method(lst):
    r = re.compile(r"(\d).*\1")
    return [i for i in lst if not r.search(str(i))]


def trincot1(lst):
    return [n for n in lst if len(set(str(n))) == len(str(n))]


def trincot2(lst):
    return [n for n in lst if len(set(s := str(n))) == len(s)]


def afaalgo(lst):
    answer = []
    for value in lst:
        value = str(value)
        new_list = []
        for nums in value:
            new_list.append(nums)
        if sorted(list(set(new_list))) == sorted(new_list):
            answer.append(int(value))
    return answer


t1 = timeit(lambda: re_method(lst), number=10)
t2 = timeit(lambda: trincot1(lst), number=10)
t3 = timeit(lambda: trincot2(lst), number=10)
t4 = timeit(lambda: afaalgo(lst), number=10)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print(t4)
```

Prints on my machine (3700x/Python 3.8.5):

```
0.2806989410019014
0.33745980000821874
0.263871792005375
0.8039937680005096
```

So version with `set()` and `:=` is fastest in this case.

Comment: I added an answer using your benchmark but in PyPy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudocode (not in Python):

```
newList <- []
for each number in oldList
  if hasNoRepeatDigits(number)
    newList.add(number)
  endif
endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [123456, 889756, 854123, 997886, 634178]

answer = []
for value in lst:
    value = str(value)
    new_list = []
    for nums in value:
        new_list.append(nums)
    if sorted(list(set(new_list))) == sorted(new_list):
        answer.append(int(value))
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PyPy, this seems about [2 to 7 times faster](https://ideone.com/Y3dF2i) than the other ones:

```py
def has_duplicates(n):
  s = 0
  while n:
    d = n % 10
    if (1<<d) & s:
      return True
    s |= 1<<d
    n = n // 10
  return False
 
def f(lst):
  return [i for i in lst if not has_duplicates(i)]
```

Comment: Thanks for PyPy version and benchmark! +1